# TensorFlow: Can we have different count of images for training and testing while training multiple objects?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to ask that is this correct or not to have a different count of images for training and testing for multiple objects using TensorFlow?

For example, I want to train 3 objects **A** and **B** and **C** using `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco` or `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco` model.

- For object **A** I have 500 images 400 for training and 100 for
  testing
- For object **B** I have 1000 images 700 for training and 300 for
  testing
- For object **C** I have 1500 image 1000 for training and 500 for
  testing

And in the `config` file change like this `num_examples: 9000`

Now the question is: Is this OK, **OR** we must have the same count of images (training and testing) for each object?

Comment: It's better to have the same number of objects in the training set. But I don't think it's mandatory.

Comment: It is not "correct" or "incorrect", it's just the nature of the data that you have. In machine learning that problem is called "class imbalance", a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=machine+learning+imbalanced+classes) should point you to interesting articles on the topic.